# AJAX requests hangs/crashes Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I have encountered rather weird bug. Upon certain AJAX request Safari hangs for *exactly* 60 seconds then shows data returned by the request. One person claims it crashes his Safari altogether (both desktop and mobile). This doesn't happen in any other browser. There doesn't seem to be anything special about this request yet it happens. There 4 possible values for `$(this).attr('data-lb-daysago')` - 7, 30, 90, 180. Problem only occurs with 30.
Here is the code:

```
$('[data-lb-daysago]').click(function ()
{
    if (parseInt($(this).attr('data-lb-daysago')) != daysago)
    {
        $('#load_more_row_lb').html(loader());
        $('[data-lb-daysago]').removeClass('active_da');
        $(this).addClass('active_da');
        $('[data-lb-last-offset]').hide();
        daysago = parseInt($(this).attr('data-lb-daysago'));
        var request = {action: 'leaderboard_ajax', daysago: daysago, offset: 0};
        $.ajax({type: "post", dataType: "json", url: ep_ajax_object.ajax_url, data: request}).done(function (e)
        {
            $('[data-lb-last-offset]').attr('data-lb-last-offset', e.offset);
            $('[data-lb-last-offset]').html(e.html);
            $('[data-lb-last-offset]').show();
            if (typeof e.nomore == 'undefined')
            {
                $('#load_more_row_lb').html('<span class="load_more_button" id="load_more_lb">Load More <span class="fi-expand-down" title="expand down" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>');
                bind_things();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#load_more_row_lb').html('<span class="load_more_button" id="load_more_lb">Load More <span class="fi-expand-down" title="expand down" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>');
                bind_things();
                $('#load_more_row_lb').hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but I will make a couple of suggestions:
1. Are there any other requests being blocked before yours? Sometimes users install Ad blockers, privacy plugins etc that block the subsequent requests from downloading, and this is especially true since Ajax calls happen later.
2. Safari has a bug (ehm, performance enhancement) that just blocks when you have more than one concurrent Ajax request, so if you have long polling or something blocked your request will also be blocked. (I had big trouble with this on iOS6, not sure if it has been fixed since)